# EF Core Migrations - how to modify the previous migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1, ef-core-2.2

I have a question about editing migration files in `EF Core`.

Example: I have created 3 tables using separate migration for each: `AddTable1`, `AddTable2`, `AddTable3`.

After that several days later I decided to change the type of `status` column in `Table1` to be `int` and not `string`.

After updating the `AddTable1` migration file, deleting the database and executing `update-database` command the column was still defined with `string` type.

I noticed that all the `.Designer.cs` files still were using `string` type for `status` column despite my edit of `Table1` migration file.

I copied the content of the `AppDbContextModelSnapshot.cs` file and manually updated all the `.Designer.cs` files for all migrations (**note**: the method name in source and `.Designer.cs` files is different).

And that helped. I'm sure that this is not the recommended way to use migrations.

My question is: is there a command which will do what I did - 'reset' the '.Designer.cs' files?

If not, how to make one? :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of migrations as Git commits. You don't rewrite previous commits once you've shared them with other team members (or in our case, applied a migration to a database). Instead, you create new migrations with additional changes.

If you haven't applied a migration or shared it with teammates, you can remove it and re-scaffold:

```
Remove-Migration
Add-Migration FixedUpMigration
```

See the [EF Core Migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/) docs for basic usage.

Comment: I know that. But I don't have team members. I'm building a project from scratch.

Comment: `dbContext.Database.EnsureDeleted()` and `EnsureCreated()` work well during early development. See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6214#issuecomment-332980580 for another crazy idea.

Comment: @denis_n I think manually merge migrations is a viable solution albeit tedious. I keep one migration per rtm release, that's how I'm doing it from time to time. Alternatively, you can delete your migrations and re-add them like bricelam pointed out.